# What is the best way to create multiple language versions of a domain?

Tags: dns, dsl

I would like to create a set of domain objects in multiple languages, so that I can target different platforms.  I have been looking at external DSLs as a way to define a language for my domain, and then potentially writing adapters that generate code for the languages I'm interested in targeting.  Is this the best way to solve this problem?  Or is it just simpler to maintain multiple versions of the project?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: My primary language is C#, but I'd like to possibly target android and iphone as well (so Java and Objective-C).

Comment: Do these domain objects have a behaviour or its just data?

Comment: They will have behavior in addition to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [Apache Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) delivers what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but as you mention C# being your main language, this practically fully supported Visual Studio based technology is exactly what you are looking for.

You have to understand what you want to abstract with your DSLs, but the multiple-platform support is trivial on top of that.

Disclaimer: This is our technology, but it's publicly open and it solves exactly the problem presented in the question.

http://abstraction.codeplex.com/

Note! Mind the very "alpha" stage of the current download, I suggest you skip the zipped download and grab the latest source. I am updating better construct in relatively near future. Check out the "Context" implementation in "Production/Dev/AbstractionTemplate" solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to be helpful without understanding what you are planning to use your DSL for.

Is portability your main problem here?
To succesfully target these different platforms, you will probably have to maintain plaftorm-specific layers anyway (generated or not).

If you plan to write your whole application in your DSL, then use your own compiler to transform it into runnable code for each platform, well it is most probably a bad idea, too complex and overengineered.

However, if you have a well-defined chunk of platform-independent logic, then a DSL is a good choice. Just write an interpreter for it on each target platform (provided that performance is not critical, this is also simpler and easier than generating code).

Comment: The thinking was to create the well defined chunk of platform-independent logic in a DSL and then use that to generate or somehow create versions in different languages.  What do you mean by an interpreter? Yes, portability would be the main concern.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to create multiple language versions of a domain?

This is (was?) somehow the idea of [Model Driven Architecture (MDA)](http://www.omg.org/mda/). Quoting [Model-driven architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture) from Wikipedia:

> The Model-Driven Architecture approach
>   defines system functionality using a
>   platform-independent model (PIM) using
>   an appropriate domain-specific
>   language (DSL).
>
> Then, given a platform definition
>   model (PDM) corresponding to CORBA,
>   .NET, the Web, etc., the PIM is
>   translated to one or more
>   platform-specific models (PSMs) that
>   computers can run. This requires
>   mappings and transformations and
>   should be modeled too.
>
> The PSM may use different Domain
>   Specific Languages (DSLs), or a
>   General Purpose Language (GPL) like
>   Java, C#, PHP, Python, etc. Automated tools generally
>   perform this translation.

Depending on the complexity of your domain and the availability of a MDA Tool, this might be an option (with a lower implementation cost).

#### See also

- [MDA: Nice idea, shame about the ...](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365166/MDA-Nice-idea-shame-about-the)
- [Language Workbenches and Model Driven Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mdaLanguageWorkbench.html)
- [UML vs. Domain-Specific Languages](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=71)
- [DSL in the context of UML and GPL](http://www.theenterprisearchitect.eu/archive/2008/08/20/dsl_in_the_context_of_uml_and_)
- [UML or DSL: Which Bear Is Best?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/ff476944.aspx) (be sure to read this one)